# After logged as root it wont execute in ubuntu linux shell script

Tags: bash, shell

Here I created a linux shell script to execute a program to echo  "User logged as root". But it wont show anything. if I give 'exit' then it will show "user logged as root". Please help me to solve this issue.

```
#!/bin/bash 
logged_user=`whoami`
if [ $logged_user != root ]
    then echo "You are not logged as root!"
    echo "Enter root password if root password is set"
    su                                #here it will ask to enter root password
    echo "user logged as root"        #this line is not working...  

fi
```

Comment: What way autostart this scenario?

Comment: Question is why this will work ??

echo "user logged as root"

Comment: I need to run commands from user logged as root only. Here I make sure to user logged as root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I need is, 
to run commands only after the user inputs the password for SU,
just split the program into two bash files

1 main.sh

```
#!/bin/bash 
logged_user=`whoami`
if [ $logged_user != root ]
    then echo "You are not logged as root!"
    echo "Enter root password if root password is set"
    su root echo_file.sh    #here it call echo_file.sh as root user    


fi
```

2 echo_file.sh

```
echo "user logged as root";
echo `whoami`
```

Answer (score 2):

The `su` starts a root shell. The command does not actually return control to your script unless you exit the shell (via `exit`). Works as designed.

If you want to have a specific *command* executed, instead of opening a shell, use it like this:

```
su -c echo "User logged as root"
```

or, even better,

```
sudo echo "User logged as root"
```

Either way, you *are* aware that, once your script ends, you will be back where you started, i.e. you will *not* get a root shell through starting a script? (Because the script itself runs in a subshell as well.)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `"` around root in your condition

```
#!/bin/bash 
logged_user=`whoami`
if [ $logged_user != "root" ]
    then echo "You are not logged as root!"
    echo "Enter root password if root password is set"
    su                                #here it will ask to enter root password
    echo "user logged as root"        #this line is not working...  

fi
```

Comment: @Ashish this is my answer, in my opinion it solve one of the issue that I noticed :)

Comment: here if condition is working fine with or without " "